# Eurostat - postcodes & LAU

Tags: postal-code

Eurostat has established a [link](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/en/web/nuts/correspondence-tables/postcodes-and-nuts) between postcodes and [NUTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenclature_of_Territorial_Units_for_Statistics) level 3 codes.

However, what I need is a link between postcodes and [LAU level 2 codes](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts/local-administrative-units). (The most detailed level of Territorial Units, usually municipalities)

In theory this should be available but I cannot find such a table. Does anybody know where I can get a list of LAU02 codes and corresponding postcodes?

Or does anybody know a source for a shapefile with all European postal codes?

Background:

I aim to work with survey data of participants form various European countries and I am interested in the degree of urbanization of the residential region of each participant. For each participant I have the postal code available. The degree of urbanization of each LAU level 2 would be available from [Eurostat](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/population-distribution-demography/degurba).

Comment: You can get UK postcode coordinates from the Ordnance Survey as part of their CodePointOpen product (free). Have you tried looking at other countries' mapping agency web sites for similar data? Its possible nobody has (yet) collected all the EU together.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I know where to find this information for my country (Switzerland). However, I should get the information from 12 European countries. I don't speak the language of most of them. This will make the work very tedious. However, this might be the way to go in the end. Thanks!

Comment: Try https://opendata.stackexchange.com but I am certain that there is no such database. Postal codes are private data in many countries.

Comment: For belgium there's no official dataset. Efforts have been made in OpenStreetMap to create boundaries though. You can query those through the overpass API, and export to GIS formats. Not sure what value the possibly incorporated data has for other regions. https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/BjA for example query, ignoring country borders and such.

Comment: UK postcodes and LAU 2 codes are available in the [ONS Postcode Directory](http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets?q=ONS%20Postcode%20Directory%20(ONSPD)%20August%202018&sort=name).

Comment: The matching from LAU/Ubanisation to zip codes is still relevant. @Michael Harrop: Thank you for the .txt-file! Still, I could not find the source to the file. Would you mind sharing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be too late for your needs but this is now [published](https://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/tercet/Various/PC_DGURBA_2018.zip) with a match to LAU/Degree of Urbanisation

Answer (score 0):

"Unfortunately, a matching table at a detail lower than NUTS 3 (i.e. LAU) does not exist. We have tried to establish such one, but there were too many issues with data availability, coherence and overall quality that it has proven impossible."

Answer by mail from the European statistical bureau of Regional Statistics and Geographical Information.